# Recreating variance shadow mapping using geometry and/or shader nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, geometry-nodes, shadows

So for the past few days I've been trying to get a simple form of variance shadow mapping (or any kind of shadow mapping) to work in Blender. In Eevee, you can of course just use a Diffuse BSDF and Shader to RGB node to get *some* access to the shadow mapping, but the Shader to BSDF node does not work in Cycles of course. And for the record I would absolutely use Eevee, but my scene is already *very* node heavy and slows Eevee down.

I believe I already understand how shadow mapping works. You create an orthogonal projection matrix (assuming a directional light is used) and a LookAt matrix and use them to transform each vertex position into screen space from the light's perspective. You can use the z coordinate of the vertex position as a depth map and save it as a texture, and from there you can compare the z coordinate/depth value at each pixel with the corresponding depth value from the depth map texture (using the x and y coordinate of the light space vertex position as mapping coordinates) and, if the 3d depth value is greater than the 2d depth value, mark that pixel as being in shadow.

The problem is that blender cannot render textures in real time. Since the 2d depth value seems to just represent the closest fragment/first fragment hit by the light direction vector, I was thinking of using the Sample Nearest node to find the closest vertex that the light direction vector intersects for each vertex position. Then I'd use use the resulting index to re-index the depth value for each vertex position. This should only affect the occluded vertices, therefore replicating shadow mapping.

[image: Scene Set-up]
[image: Node Set-up and 2D depth values]
[image: Different arrangement of shadows]

As you can see, the shadows are somewhat there, but they're very wonky and don't really behave like shadows? And the 2D Depth Values for vertices directly visible to the light should not change. I'm almost certain the problem is the sample position field, but I don't really know what to change.

[image]

Comment: maybe i am naive and i have to admit, i didn't even look at your file, but if you wanna make shadows with direction lights, sample nearest can only be wrong because it doesn't car about direction. I would use raycast for that which "holds" the direction.

Comment: Might end up using Raycast if I can't find another option, but I wanted to avoid using it since it's not done via shadow mapping (I am specifically trying to replicate shadow mapping)